# Doctrine Console program

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am learning Doctrine. I config doctrine 2.2.0 by Tarball Download. Now getting trouble when generating-the-database-schema. Can't use command-line tool with the code below:

```
<?php
// doctrine.php - Put in your application root

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;

$lib = "../DoctrineORM-2.2.0";
require $lib . '/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php';
Setup::registerAutoloadDirectory($lib);

$paths = array("/path/to/entities-or-mapping-files");
$isDevMode = false;

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$dbParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'
);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$helperSet = new HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

The error here.

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper' not found in E:\wamp\www\project\doctrine.php on line 30

and I can not find  EntityManagerHelper.php under DoctrineORM-2.2.0\Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper   .

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [`EntityManagerHelper`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Helper/EntityManagerHelper.php) is under different namespace:

`namespace Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper;`

Comment: Yep.  And if you follow the examples to add some commands then you will run into several more of these typos.  But it will work eventually.